# HiddenField coming back as blank in the code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview where the information for this grid is entered in by textboxes. I then click a save button and this information gets saved to the grid.
For one of these textboxes it brings up a menu. The user selects a creditor from the menu and the creditor id gets saved in the HiddenField.

```
<td class="tblAddDetail" style="border-right:2px">
   <a style="float:left;width:16px;height:16px;margin-right:0px;left:0px;top:1px" title="Pick from list..." class="iconSearch" id="btnAddDetailCreditor"></a>
   <asp:HiddenField ID="hfCreditorID" runat="server"  />
   <input type="text" id="txtAddEditCreditorCode" class="lookuppopup" onblur="CheckCreditorAccountDetail(this.value)" style="text-transform:uppercase;width:80px" runat="server"/>
 </td>
```

When the user selects a creditor from the list this function runs which populates the textbox with the name and the HiddenField with the id:

```
function CheckCreditorAccountDetail(AC) {
            //AJAX Save
            if ($.trim(AC).length) {
                PageMethods.GetCreditorAccountCode(AC,
                                            OnCheckCreditorDetail,
                                            null
                                            );
            }
        }

 function OnCheckCreditorDetail(result) {
 $('#<%= hfCreditorID.ClientID %>').val(result.ID);
            $('#<%= txtAddEditCreditorCode.ClientID %>').val(result.AccountCode);
}
```

It calls a `WebMethod` which finds the creditor in the database:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static Creditor GetCreditorAccountCode(string AccountCode)
    {
        try
        {
            Creditor c = new Creditor(AccountCode);
            return c;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new Creditor();
        }
    }
```

If the `WebMethod` returns a value it populates the hiddenfield and textbox. So `result` is the creditor and calling `result.AccountCode` gives the creditors account code etc.

But when I try call this HiddenField in the code behind it is always blank:

```
if (!int.TryParse(hfCreditorID.Value, out tmpCredID))
{
    valid = false;
}
```

The problem is when I click the save button it causes a post back so I lose all the values. It's not the hiddenfield that is losing its value the textbox is also coming back blank

Comment: `this.value` is just a text, a string, it won't have `ID` field

Comment: @Andrei It finds the ID value from `result.ID` which does have a value. It is just a number. The problem is calling `hfCreditorID.Value` in the code behind is coming back as blank

Comment: @Andrei Please see my edited question. I had left out some functions but hopefully this explains the issue better

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing/trying to mix javascript and C# used in code behind.

You are sending `result` (which is a string in javascript as Andrei already points out) and try to access properties that do not exist. `result.AccountCode`?

Your javascript function names do not match `CheckCreditorAccountDetail` and `OnCheckCreditorDetail`.

Why a HiddenField if you can get the values directly from the TextBox in code behind?
See my snippet for a working example.

On the .aspx page:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfCreditorID" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAddEditCreditorCode" runat="server" onblur="OnCheckCreditorDetail(this.value)"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnCheckCreditorDetail(result) {
        $('#<%= hfCreditorID.ClientID %>').val(result);
     }
</script>
```

And in code behind:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtAddEditCreditorCode.Text = hfCreditorID.Value + " - OK";
        //or just get the values from the TextBox without a HiddenField
        txtAddEditCreditorCode.Text = txtAddEditCreditorCode.Text + " - OK";
    }
```

Comment: Please see my edited question. I had left out some functions but hopefully this explains the issue better

Comment: I tried using textboxes instead of a hiddenfield but loses its value to

Comment: Try a blank page with only my snippet. If that works build from there. You are probably losing the values on postback somewhere.